# ReactJs : unable to reset input field to ""

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm having application with **React v 0.13.1 (Old version)**.
I'm unable to update my input field to "" after fetching updated value from DB.

Scenario: I'm updating the input fields by clicking on button "Pull". Functionality of this button is to fetch the data from a separate DB and then save the data in my DB to update the input fields value.

**Child Component code:**

```
<div>
  <div
    style={this.props.Styles.divItem}
    data-id={this.props.AddressArray["flat_no"]}
  >
    <div style={this.props.Styles.label}>Flat no.</div>
    <Input
      Type="text"
      Value={this._getValue(this.props.AddressArray["flat_no"])}
      ValueChanged={(value) =>
        this._DataItemValueChanged(value, this.props.AddressArray["flat_no"])
      }
    />
  </div>
</div>;
```

Method to fetch input field value

```
    _getValue(itemId) {
        
        var currentValue = this.props.Details[this.props.Section][itemId];

        if(currentValue === undefined) {
            return "";
        }

        return currentValue.Value;
    },
```

There is a separate method to fetch data from DB and populate props, which is doing its job.
But the input field is not getting updated if its blank i.e. "". If it has any value like 9, it will update.
Also it will reset as blank after pulling data only if I refresh the page, else it will sustain its old value.

Can anyone please guide me on how to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Let see why it is not working**

- You may dont have `handleInputChange` handler

Let see how we can solve this

- consider `ShowEdit` is your component name
- there is loader to load data form your local db before render componet
- there is a action method for form action to submit
- `isPull` state variable to pull form separate db and re render component
- `navigator` use to reset after submit

```
import {Form, useActionData, useLoaderData, useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap";

function ShowEdit() {

    const actionDataAfterSave = useActionData();
    const flat = useLoaderData();
    const navigator = useNavigate();
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState(flat);
    const [isPull, setIsPull] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {

        let flat_no = flat.flat_no;
        let url = 'url-to-your-seperate-db-application/get-flat-info?flat_no='+flat_no;
        let flatFromRemoteDb = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(response => response.json());
        setFormData(flatFromRemoteDb);

    }, [setIsPull]);


    useEffect(() => {

         if(actionDataAfterSave) {
             // reset
             navigator('/show-edit')
         }

    }, [actionDataAfterSave]);


    const onPullHandaler = () => {
        setIsPull(true);

    }
    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setFormData((previousState) => {
            return {...previousState, [name] :value}
        })
    }



    return (
        <>

            <Form method='post'>


                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">
                        Flat no.
                    </label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        name="name"
                        value={formData.flat_no}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="mb-3">
                    Other form fields here
                </div>


                <Button variant="primary" onClick={onPullHandaler}>
                    Pull
                </Button>
                <Button type='submit' variant="primary">
                    Submit
                </Button>


            </Form>

        </>
    );
}

export default ShowEdit;

export async function loader({params}) {

    let flat_no = params.flat_no;
    let url = 'url-to-your-local-db-application/get-flat-info?flat_no=' + flat_no;
    let flat = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(response => response.json());

    return flat;
}

export const action = async ({request}) => {
    let flat;
    let reqObject = {}
    const formData = await request.formData();
    formData.forEach((value, key) => (reqObject[key] = value));

    let url =  reqObject.id ? `path-to-your-local-db-update-action` : `path-to-your-local-db-save-action`;
    let method = reqObject.id ? 'PUT' : 'POST';


    try{
        flat = await fetch(url, {
            method: method,
            body: JSON.stringify(reqObject),
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(response => response.json());

    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return {success : 0, msg : 'Something went wrong.'}
    }

    return flat;
}
```

- now your router config will be like below in main.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import {createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider} from 'react-router-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import {action as myAction, loader as myLoader} from './ShowEdit.jsx';
import ShowEdit from "./components/routeComponents/ShowEdit.jsx";
import Home from "./components/routeComponents/Home.jsx";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: '/', element: <Home/>
    },

    {
        path: '/', element: <ShowEdit />,
        loader : myLoader,
        action: myAction
    }

]);


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

Comment: As shared in my post I'm having application with React v 0.13.6 (Old version). Thus require solution that will work with this version only.

Comment: @ASHISH_TECHIT thanks you take the idea form my answer. i'll try to update my answer as per React v 0.13.6 . But need some time